# Coordinate Transformation from Uniform Gravitational Field to Minkowski Coordinates

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, gravity, coordinate-systems

I've heard that because the metric for a uniform gravitational field was flat, there existed a coordinate transformation which could remove the effect of gravity(I.E. transform to Minkowski coordinates). I made the assumption that objects at z=0 in the gravity frame felt constant proper acceleration g and moved along the hyperbolic path
$$z\left(ct\right)=\sqrt{\frac{c^4}{g^2}+\left(ct\right)^2}$$
I then decided that an event happens at coordinate [ct,0,0,z] in the gravitational frame and figured out when null geodesics from that event would intersect with the z=0 path in Minkowski coordinates. Using all that, I created the following coordinate transformation:

If an event happens at [ct,z] in the uniform gravity frame, it'll happen at
$$\frac{c^2}{g}e^{1-e^{-\frac{gz}{c^2}}}\left[\begin{matrix}\sinh{\left(\frac{gct}{c^2}\right)}\\\cosh{\left(\frac{gct}{c^2}\right)}\\\end{matrix}\right]$$
in the Minkowski coordinates(top coordinate is ct and bottom coordinate is z). This issue I'm seeing is observers at different z's in the gravitational frame seem to experience different proper acceleration. I was expecting all observers would have the same path in Minkowski coordinates but shifted a bit. What went wrong and what's the actual transformation? As it stands, it just looks like mislabeled Rindler coordinates.